# HttpURLConnection.getResponse code Error

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

In my android application I'm trying to check if there is internet access and if there is to download some data. However when I run the code below to validate the connection the .getResponseCode() method it returns -1 instead of 200 even though there is a valid connection. The device is connected to internet through both 4G or WIFI but it does not work. Other applications installed on the device can access the internet.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

AndroidManifests.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sg.help">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**UPDATE** Added the following output from Debug. As you can see the responseCode is -1.

```
urlc = {HttpURLConnectionImpl@19895} "com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://www.google.com"
 client = {OkHttpClient@19909} 
 handshake = null
 httpEngine = {HttpEngine@19910} 
 httpEngineFailure = null
 requestHeaders = {Headers$Builder@19911} 
 route = {Route@19912} 
 fixedContentLength = -1
 redirectionCount = 0
 method = {String@19913} "GET"
 responseMessage = null
 fixedContentLengthLong = -1
 chunkLength = -1
 fixedContentLength = -1
 instanceFollowRedirects = true
 responseCode = -1
 contentType = null
 defaultHandler = {URLConnection$DefaultContentHandler@19914} 
 url = {URL@19883} "http://www.google.com"
 allowUserInteraction = false
 ifModifiedSince = 0
 lastModified = -1
 connectTimeout = 0
 connected = true
 doInput = true
 doOutput = false
 readTimeout = 0
 useCaches = true
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@17437} "class com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1761921262
```

Comment: post the stacktrace please.

Comment: @AxeFox Hi. I have edited my post with the debug log. Not sure if it's the correct one.

Comment: You need to close the input stream of the `HttpURLConnection` after you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your URL, such as https://www.android.com/. Also, try disconnecting your httpconnection afterwards to see if it helps.

> Disconnect. Once the response body has been read, the HttpURLConnection should be closed by calling disconnect(). Disconnecting releases the resources held by a connection so they may be closed or reused.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Try the following.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.android.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    urlc.disconnect();
                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing the url fixed the issue